# unable to display data from list

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

for some reason it isnt displaying the dates anything wrong with it?

```
IsolatedStorageSettings uc = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;

public void load()
        {
            List<DateTime> List = new List<DateTime>();
            Schedule.ItemsSource = null;
            List<s> medicationList = (List<s>)uc["nList"];

            foreach(sn temp in List)
            {
                if (dateList.Contains(t.Date))
                {

                }
                else
                {                    
                    date.Add(t.Date);
                    Schedule.ItemsSource = List;
                }
            }
        }
```

Stupid mistake (Solution)

```
<ListBox x:Name="Schedule" >
</ListBox>
```

The those and remove unnecessary codes

Comment: 1) What is your xaml? 
2) Do not set the ItemsSource in the foreach loop

Comment: Can you show the declaration of uc?

Comment: Wow, that's kind of a basic error there.

Comment: Hi @Will♦, may i know whats the error there because even with the ItemsSource out of the for loop, it still doesnt display. THanks

Comment: You should 1) pick up CLR via C#, and 2) pick up a good WPF book (not sure which one).  It will serve you well down the road.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a start, move `lstboxSchedule.ItemsSource = dateList;` outside the foreach.

Set breakpoints to see if/why the list produced is empty.

Comment: I tried to debug and its showing that the value is added into the Schedule but for some reason its not displaying it.
Is it due to some kind of formatting? eg maybe i have to Schedule.ItemsSource = List.toString??? ;

Comment: @RainbowHat please update the question with the xaml where you declare Schedule.

Comment: @RainbowHat if you've found the solution, it would be good to add the solution at the end of the question for future reference.